# html5 streaming a video to multiple browsers and keep the video synchronized on all browsers

Tags: html, video-streaming

So I got 9 Samsung The Frame LS03's and I have to play one .mp4 file on all of them synchronized. I want to accomplish this with HTML5. I got access to a windows server
So far I had this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TheFrame LS03 SynchroSite</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>

</html>`
```

I need this question answerd as quick as possible because I have limited time to do this.
Thanks in advance
Linus E.

Comment: The Frame LS03's have a browser app that basicly is just chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone asking I've finished this project by using socket.io and express to create a webserver and keep all browsers synchronized with socket.io.
If you want to look into it I have the sourcecode up on github: https://github.com/f4ls3/Synchronization